# Ansible add EC2 with add_host but connection gives missing Python error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have used Ansible to create 1 AWS EC2 instance using the examples in the [Ansible `ec2` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/ec2_module.html#examples). I can successfully create the instance with a tag. Then I temporarily add it to my local inventory group using `add_host`.

After doing this, I am having trouble when I try to configure the newly created instance. In my Ansible play, I would like to specify the instance by its tag name. eg. `hosts: <tag_name_here>`, but I am getting an error.

Here is what I have done so far:

My directory layout is

```
inventory/
   staging/
      hosts
      group_vars/
         all/
            all.yml

site.yml
```

My `inventory/staging/hosts` file is

```
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local  ansible_python_interpreter=/home/localuser/ansible_ec2/.venv/bin/python
```

My `inventory/staging/group_vars/all/all.yml` file is

```
---
ami_image: xxxxx
subnet_id: xxxx
region: xxxxx
launched_tag: tag_Name_NginxDemo
```

Here is my Ansible playbook `site.yml`

```
- name: Launch instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ec2:
         key_name: key-nginx
         group: web_sg
         instance_type: t2.micro
         image: "{{ ami_image }}"
         wait: true
         region: "{{ region }}"
         vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet_id }}"
         assign_public_ip: yes
         instance_tags:
           Name: NginxDemo
           exact_count: 1
         count_tag:
           Name: NginxDemo
           exact_count: 1
      register: ec2

    - name: Add EC2 instance to inventory group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: tag_Name_NginxDemo
        ansible_user: centos_user
        ansible_become: yes
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: Configure EC2 instance in launched group
  hosts: tag_Name_NginxDemo
  become: True
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

I run this playbook with

```
$ cd /home/localuser/ansible_ec2
$ source .venv/bin/activate
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/staging site.yml -vvv`
```

and this creates the EC2 instance - the 1st play works correctly. However, the 2nd play gives the following error

```
TASK [.....] ******************************************************************
The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx.xxx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
fatal: [xx.xxx.xxx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": 
"Shared connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xx closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 
1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 127}
```

I followed the instructions from

- [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45203080/4057186) to create the task with `add_hosts`
- [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19605#issuecomment-324075731) to set `gather_facts: False`, but this still does not allow the play to run correctly.

How can I target the EC2 host using the tag name?

**EDIT:**

Additional info

This is the only playbook I have run to this point. I see this message requires Python but I cannot install Python on the instance as I cannot connect to it in my play `Configure EC2 instance in launched group`...if I could make that connection, then I could install Python (if this is the problem). Though, I'm not sure how to connect to the instance.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my Python info on the localhost where I am running Ansible

I am running Ansible inside a Python venv.

Here is my python inside the venv

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1

$ which python
~/ansible_ec2/.venv/bin/python
```

Here are my details about Ansible that I installed inside the Python venv

```
ansible 2.6.2
  config file = /home/localuser/ansible_ec2/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/localuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/localuser/ansible_ec2/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/localuser/ansible_ec2/.venv/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, xxxx, xxxx) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/python: not found` means that `/usr/bin/python` was **not found**. You need to address that. How? Nobody knows, because you give no details. There can only be guesses.

Comment: Thanks. So far, I have just run the playbook I posted. I have created the EC2 instance though I have not installed anything on it. Do you mean I need to install Python on the instance?

Comment: If it is not installed, then likely yes. The information `xxxxx`, which you posted in the question, is not very informative for SO readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of searching, I found 1 possible workaround [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21468#issuecomment-280187662). Basically, this workaround uses the `lineinfile` module and adds the new EC2 instance details to the `hosts` file permanently....not just for the in-memory plays following the `add_host` task. I followed this suggestion very closely and this approach worked for me. I did not need to use the `add_host` module.

**EDIT:**

The line I added in the `lineinfile` module was

```
- name: Add EC2 instance to inventory group
  - lineinfile: line="{{ item.public_ip }} ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3" insertafter=EOF dest=./inventory/staging/hosts
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```